# Concurrent requests to TwilioRestClient create API gives http 409

Tags: java, rest, http, concurrency, twilio

I am trying to use TwilioRestClient API for creating bindings. I have to read the inputs from a file and then create bindings for each of them. As there are thousands of records, I tried parallel processing. But that gives me http 409 sometimes. If I don't use parallel processing, I get 100 percent success. But as I increase the no of threads, the success percentage decreases.

```
Callable task = () -> {

// Call to TwilioRestClient create bindings goes here.
}

ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(8); //Utilising 8 cores
List<Bindings> bindings = (List<Bindings>) pool.submit(task).get();
```

I expect the bindings to be created for all the records that are read from the file and passed to the API. When parallel processing is tried with 8 cores, out of 1000 records around 800 succeeds. As I decrease the no of cores, the success rate increases. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Twilio API has a [concurrency limit of 100 concurrent connections](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002943027-Understanding-Twilio-Rate-Limits-and-Message-Queues). My guess is, though I don't have much experience with concurrency and threading in Java, that as you increase your thread count you bump up against the concurrency limit and that is why requests are failing.

I would recommend dialling back until you make less than 100 concurrent connections, which should lead to you making 100% successful requests. I can't suggest how you can achieve this within your codebase though, sorry.